# Unable to open Sitecore Experience Editor. Tracker.Current not initialized. Sitecore 9.0

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9

We are having an issue when we open the Experience Editor. The Experience Editor encounters an error:

> Tracker.Current is not initialized.

Does anyone encounter this?

Below is the error log:

```
    7712 06:11:08 ERROR Cannot create tracker.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Could not find type 'Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.LoadEmailRenderSessionContact, Sitecore.EmailCampaign'
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromServiceProvider(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetObjectFromType(XmlNode processorNode)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetProcessorObject(XmlNode processorNode)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.GetMethod(Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.EnsureSessionContextPipeline.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Run>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Monitor>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func`1 operation)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.EnsureSessionContext()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateTracker.GetTracker.Process(CreateTrackerArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Initialize()
```

What are we missing?

Comment: Does this happen every time you load the experience editor?

Comment: I'm having issues that are related to yours. You can see my questions on stack exchange: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16536/how-to-fix-500-error-in-sitecore-ribbon-on-first-experience-editor-preview-mod  and https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16532/how-to-fix-system-reflection-reflectiontypeloadexception-when-loading-types-from

Comment: @Marcel Yes, everitime I load the experience editor

Comment: What type of server does this live on? Does it only happen locally, or does it also happen upstream?

Comment: You are going to need to compare your bin folder with a vanilla 9.0 instance. I think a bad version of a Sitecore dll has snuck into your site. I use Beyond Compare.